# Saving a file in a location with new file name each time in java

Tags: java, processbuilder

I am using process builder to run my external program and the external program generate some files. I am using the following code to save the file

```
     Process en = new ProcessBuilder("E:\\Encryption.exe",file.getAbsolutePath(),
"E:\\key_abc.key","E:\\encypted_img.jpg").start();
```

This can save my all the files generate from the process. But how to save the files in a location with new file name each time? Because when I run the program the previous files are replacing.

Comment: Append a Date/Time to the file name.

Comment: Can you give an example sir @DevilsHnd